# bbb-install: You must run this command on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, bigbluebutton

I am trying to integrate BigBlueButton with Asp.Net c# on [Windows 10 with Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview).
installing BigBlueButton you have three choices: [bbb-install.sh](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html)

```
#  Install BigBlueButton with SSL + Greenlight
#
#    wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v xenial-22 -s bbb.example.com -e info@example.com -g
#
```

Continously getting bbb-install: You must run this command on Ubuntu 16.04 server.
I am unable to get link or docs for installing Ubuntu 16.04 server on windows 10.
Is there any commands can we use on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS??

Answer (score 0):

BigBlueButton Version 2.3.* comes with ubuntu 18
use the following link

```
wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v bionic-230-dev -s bbb.example.com -e mail@example.com -a -w
```

Comment: Thanx for ur reply ans.The above err is gone. But still unable to install BBB facing new err "Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bbb-etherpad
 bbb-demo
 bbb-record-core
 bbb-playback-presentation
 bbb-html5
 bbb-libreoffice-docker
 mongodb-org-server
 bbb-web
 mongodb-org
 bbb-config
 bbb-webrtc-sfu
 bigbluebutton".can u help ??